# Incremental pipeline with parameter using Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

Is it possible to create a parameter from a table in Big Query, in this case the max ID (last row inserted), to use as start point for an incremental pipeline using Data Fusion?

I'm using Data Fusion for the pipeline, it pulls data from a MySQL database and inserts in a Big Query table, but I want to pull incremental data from MySQL, using the currently max ID from the Big Query table as start point, that means to pull from MySQL only the rows that have ID greater than the max ID in Big Query.

Comment: Do you have enable the [replication in your MySQL database](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/mysql-to-bigquery#enable_replication_in_your_mysql_database)? This replication job makes a snapshot and any change made to the table is replicated to BigQuery. Additionally, you can use [`Aggregate functions`](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/plugins#section-4) to search for the max `ID` in your BigQuery table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you can use plugin "BigQuery Execute"

and in SQL block write query on the BQ table (select max(last_row_inserted) as **parameter_1** form BQ_table)

and click on "Row As Arguments".

Now you can use/pass the **parameter_1** as runtime parameter to fetch data from source table.